# My kernel runs normally in qemu,but double fault in bochs

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, kernel

My kernel crashes when it executes the first page fault executes.
And my page fault handler looks like this:

```
asm_page_error_wrapper:
    PUSHA  
    movl %esp, %esi
    pushl 48(%esi)/*esp,pusha has already been calculated*/
    pushl 32(%esi)/*error*/
    CALL page_error_interrupt
    popl %ecx
    popl %ecx
    POPA
    addl $4, %esp
    IRET
```

In gdb it crashed at "`pushl 48(%esi)`".

Here is what the bochs log said:

[image]
I don't know the reason.

Comment: In your kernel config, are any paravirtual device drivers enabled?  These will be specific to a particular hypervisor.

Comment: Do you mean the bochs config or my kernel interrupt installer?

Comment: You compiled this kernel binary yourself, right?  The build process relies heavily on a `.config` file, which is usually created with the help of `make oldconfig`, `make menuconfig`, or `make xconfig`.

Comment: The kernel is just little and written by me, it runs normal in qemu, but crashes under bochs.

Comment: If this is a kernel you wrote yourself, you really really should make that clear in the question.  Because when you use the `linux` and `kernel` tags, it makes people think you're having trouble with the linux kernel.  And "my kernel" can simply mean "the kernel on my computer".

Comment: Thank you I just hope more people can help, do you have any suggest to debug, I am totally at a loss.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11792/discussion-between-venus-w-and-ben-voigt)

Comment: The error "gate descriptor is not valid sys seg" is pretty specific. If I remember correctly, you must have a null segment, and you will need code and data segments. How are you setting them? You may want to compare them to this: http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/4.-The%20GDT%20and%20IDT.html

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot it appears that your `IDT` is invalid for the #GP handler entry. I'm not sure how you have concluded that the crash was at `pushl 48(%esi)`. It's possible, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

If emulators produce different results, there can be just a few reasons for that:

1. Your code manipulates uninitialized data (in registers or memory)
2. There's a race condition in your code
3. There's an emulation bug

Comment: The gdb show an interrupt occurs when it goes on "push 48(%esi)". That' where my conclusion come from.